# Jump to list item from link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a UL in one div and an a-z list in another div. When I click a letter, d for example the list will jump to the first item starting with d.

I have it roughly working, but need some help to iron out the bugs. It doesn't always go to the item I'm looking for. If I click w for example it jumps to m and if I click w again it jumps to j. If I keep clicking w it will jump back and forth between m and j. It seems much worse as it gets toward the bottom of the list. I need to use className, not id as this is an auto generated list. Any help would be much appreciated. I'm very new to javascript and can't figure it out.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="file:///c:/media/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container {width: 100%;}
#leftbox {float: left; width: 30%;}
#rightbox {float: right; width: 60%; border: solid 1px #000000; height: 
200px; overflow: scroll;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="leftbox">
<a class="playalpha" href="a">A</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="b">B</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="c">C</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="d">D</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="e">E</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="f">F</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="g">G</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="h">H</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="i">I</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="j">J</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="k">K</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="l">L</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="m">M</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="n">N</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="o">O</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="p">P</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="q">Q</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="r">R</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="s">S</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="t">T</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="u">U</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="v">V</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="w">W</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="x">X</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="y">Y</a>
<a class="playalpha" href="z">Z</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.playalpha').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var letter = $(this).attr('href');
    //scroll to first h1.name element that begins with "letter"
    var target = $('.play').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase().indexOf(letter) == 0
    });
    $('html,body,div').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 400);
});
</script>
</div>
<div id="rightbox">
<ul>
<li class="play">a1</li>
<li class="play">a2</li>
<li class="play">a3</li>
<li class="play">b1</li>
<li class="play">b2</li>
<li class="play">b3</li>
<li class="play">c1</li>
<li class="play">c2</li>
<li class="play">c3</li>
<li class="play">d1</li>
<li class="play">d2</li>
<li class="play">d3</li>
<li class="play">e1</li>
<li class="play">e2</li>
<li class="play">e3</li>
<li class="play">f1</li>
<li class="play">f2</li>
<li class="play">f3</li>
<li class="play">g1</li>
<li class="play">g2</li>
<li class="play">g3</li>
<li class="play">h1</li>
<li class="play">h2</li>
<li class="play">h3</li>
<li class="play">i1</li>
<li class="play">i2</li>
<li class="play">i3</li>
<li class="play">j1</li>
<li class="play">j2</li>
<li class="play">j3</li>
<li class="play">k1</li>
<li class="play">k2</li>
<li class="play">k3</li>
<li class="play">l1</li>
<li class="play">l2</li>
<li class="play">l3</li>
<li class="play">m1</li>
<li class="play">m2</li>
<li class="play">m3</li>
<li class="play">n1</li>
<li class="play">n2</li>
<li class="play">n3</li>
<li class="play">o1</li>
<li class="play">o2</li>
<li class="play">o3</li>
<li class="play">p1</li>
<li class="play">p2</li>
<li class="play">p3</li>
<li class="play">q1</li>
<li class="play">q2</li>
<li class="play">q3</li>
<li class="play">r1</li>
<li class="play">r2</li>
<li class="play">r3</li>
<li class="play">s1</li>
<li class="play">s2</li>
<li class="play">s3</li>
<li class="play">t1</li>
<li class="play">t2</li>
<li class="play">t3</li>
<li class="play">u1</li>
<li class="play">u2</li>
<li class="play">u3</li>
<li class="play">v1</li>
<li class="play">v2</li>
<li class="play">v3</li>
<li class="play">w1</li>
<li class="play">w2</li>
<li class="play">w3</li>
<li class="play">x1</li>
<li class="play">x2</li>
<li class="play">x3</li>
<li class="play">y1</li>
<li class="play">y2</li>
<li class="play">y3</li>
<li class="play">z1</li>
<li class="play">z2</li>
<li class="play">z3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tlm2408/9yrd8k72/2/)

Comment: It is better you add a data attribute with the letter when populating the list for faster performance.

Comment: @Greg I have worked a little on this. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh214/9yrd8k72/6/. You'll need to work on it a little more.

Comment: @YogeshMistry Thank you that kind of works. I'll have a play with it.

Comment: I can sort of get it working, but I need to either click the same letter again or a before clicking another letter. I'm out of ideas. I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: I'm not sure why the offset() of the same element changes when you click it twice in a row but that might give you a clue as to where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

Try href with '#id'

No need to use javascript/jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/mmghori/9y1saarc/

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftbox">
        <a class="playalpha" href="#a">A</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#b">B</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#c">C</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#d">D</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#e">E</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#f">F</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#g">G</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#h">H</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#i">I</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#j">J</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#k">K</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#l">L</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#m">M</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#n">N</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#o">O</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#p">P</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#q">Q</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#r">R</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#s">S</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#t">T</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#u">U</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#v">V</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#w">W</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#x">X</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#y">Y</a>
        <a class="playalpha" href="#z">Z</a>

    </div>
    <div id="rightbox">
        <ul>
            <li id="a" class="play">a1</li>
            <li class="play">a2</li>
            <li class="play">a3</li>
            <li id="b" class="play">b1</li>
            <li class="play">b2</li>
            <li class="play">b3</li>
            <li id="c" class="play">c1</li>
            <li class="play">c2</li>
            <li class="play">c3</li>
            <li id="d" class="play">d1</li>
            <li class="play">d2</li>
            <li class="play">d3</li>
            <li id="e" class="play">e1</li>
            <li class="play">e2</li>
            <li class="play">e3</li>
            <li id="f" class="play">f1</li>
            <li class="play">f2</li>
            <li class="play">f3</li>
            <li id="g" class="play">g1</li>
            <li class="play">g2</li>
            <li class="play">g3</li>
            <li id="h" class="play">h1</li>
            <li class="play">h2</li>
            <li class="play">h3</li>
            <li id="i" class="play">i1</li>
            <li class="play">i2</li>
            <li class="play">i3</li>
            <li id="j" class="play">j1</li>
            <li class="play">j2</li>
            <li class="play">j3</li>
            <li id="k" class="play">k1</li>
            <li class="play">k2</li>
            <li class="play">k3</li>
            <li id="l" class="play">l1</li>
            <li class="play">l2</li>
            <li class="play">l3</li>
            <li id="m" class="play">m1</li>
            <li class="play">m2</li>
            <li class="play">m3</li>
            <li id="n" class="play">n1</li>
            <li class="play">n2</li>
            <li class="play">n3</li>
            <li id="o" class="play">o1</li>
            <li class="play">o2</li>
            <li class="play">o3</li>
            <li id="p" class="play">p1</li>
            <li class="play">p2</li>
            <li class="play">p3</li>
            <li id="q" class="play">q1</li>
            <li class="play">q2</li>
            <li class="play">q3</li>
            <li id="r" class="play">r1</li>
            <li class="play">r2</li>
            <li class="play">r3</li>
            <li id="s" class="play">s1</li>
            <li class="play">s2</li>
            <li class="play">s3</li>
            <li id="t" class="play">t1</li>
            <li class="play">t2</li>
            <li class="play">t3</li>
            <li id="u" class="play">u1</li>
            <li class="play">u2</li>
            <li class="play">u3</li>
            <li id="v" class="play">v1</li>
            <li class="play">v2</li>
            <li class="play">v3</li>
            <li id="w" class="play">w1</li>
            <li class="play">w2</li>
            <li class="play">w3</li>
            <li id="x" class="play">x1</li>
            <li class="play">x2</li>
            <li class="play">x3</li>
            <li id="y" class="play">y1</li>
            <li class="play">y2</li>
            <li class="play">y3</li>
            <li id="z" class="play">z1</li>
            <li class="play">z2</li>
            <li class="play">z3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @mmghori, Thank you, but I can't use ID because the list is generated by another script. This is just a demo I put together for here.

Comment: @yogesh sorry first time fiddler